# 'screen.linux': unknown terminal type

Tags: debian, terminal, gnu-screen, openvz

When I run `clear` I get:

> 'screen.linux': unknown terminal type

I get this error message when, on a Debian 7 machine running the OpenVZ kernel, from within a screen session, I `vzctl enter` into a Debian 8 container.

Now, I know I can just fix this by changing $TERM from 'screen.linux' to 'linux'. That's not my question. My question is twofold:

- Why doesn't this happen from within the screen session normally? Before I enter the container, $TERM is 'screen.linux', but `clear` works fine, and
- If it has anything to do with the terminfo database, how could I fix that so this doesn't happen (and I don't need to change TERM anywhere)?

Comment: You need to start a proper interactive shell after vzctl enter and there are multiple ways to do that: `su -`  or `. .bashrc` or `. .bash_profile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the `ncurses-term` package which adds many additional terminal types.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [vzctl](https://openvz.org/Man/vzctl.8) manual in the context of your question:

> **`enter`** *CTID* [`--exec` *command* *[arg ...]]*
>
> Enters into a container (giving a container’s root shell). This option is a back-door for host root only. The proper way to have CT root shell is to use ssh(1).

sounds as if it is talking about a [`chroot`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_root), which would make the shell see only the files which were provided.  Likely the container does not have a complete terminal database.  It might have the `infocmp` utility, which prints the pathname for an entry first in a comment (making it useful for checking if the terminal database is missing things such as `screen.linux`).

Comment: +1 because I didn't realize `vzctl enter` isn't the "proper" way to get a root shell on a CT.